Caching signed binaries in git repo to avoid rebuilding
I feel I'm in a bit of a conundrum, I feel in strong disagreement with my boss's solution but I don't want to argue without good reasoning. I am looking for opinions on either side to help me sway my feeling about this, I am open to changing my mind.
My boss is adamant on caching the drivers that we build + sign in the source code repository itself. That is, a folder in the repository holds the signed drivers from the most recent build.
Updating these files would be a manual step after build, somebody must commit them back to the repo.
These drivers do not change often, and the signing process is lengthy, that is why we want to cache them -- but I feel caching them inside the source code repo is a mistake.
Note, our build has several layers of caching -- first it will check if the same version driver exists in the repo and use that. Next, it will check if a previous build already ran and reuse the signed driver in the output directory if the built driver is unchanged.
On one hand, if somebody forgets to update the repo with the new driver it will cause at least one signing process to run until the local output directory is updated, then that will be used as a cache for future builds.
On the other hand if we do not cache the signed driver in the repo then a fresh checkout of the repo will always induce signing, even if the driver hasn't changed anytime recently.
I understand storing copies of binaries inflates the repository size and time to do certain actions, but the sentiment around that is that it's not a big deal.
Where does this practice fall on the acceptability scale? What are people's opinions?

It comes with a cost. The decision on whether or not to pay it is not yours to make.

Unfortunately it's really not my decision that's why I'm here, if it was my decision we wouldn't be caching binaries in the repo. I'm hoping to get more evidence for why I am correct, or reasoning for why I am wrong.

The caching approach is wrong. Make use of published packages/releases (wherever you host you git repo). Make use of branches and setup a CI/CD pipeline that if merged on a specific branch will automatically sign and make a new release with the signed driver. That way you don't sign drivers that are in development but on a specified release (triggered by a MR/PL on the desired branch, most commonly main/master). Hope this approach helps.


The caching approach is wrong -- Unfortunately the issue isn't deciding that it's wrong, I already feel that way. I need to convince somebody else (my boss of all people) that they are wrong, and that doing all this other work is both worth it and correct.  Unless I can give them a big 'why' for both why it's wrong, and why this approach is so much better, they will shrug off this answer. Thanks for taking time to reply.


Well, the 1st and obvious reason is that this, in regards to the caching approach, will work since it's a standard way to go. Plus since it's standardised approach, it offers much more flexibility in regards to what are you trying to accomplish, basically to suit your every need. If you would have some hurdles along the way or modifications requested, it won't be a problem, or to go for scale or literally any other idea. Caching wouldn't accommodate this, but would require basically hack after hack, and we all know what happens after that (problems after problems), requiring more manual work.

Just tell him to make a smarter choice, to do things the way they are supposed to do, and not to try to hack through things that are a really bad idea to hack through, especially in the long run (and for semantically important things). He will only face headaches, problems, unmet quotas, stalls, and loss of time, nerves and funds in the long run. Speaking from experience on this one, been on the receiving end. Just do what is supposed to be done and everyone will be happy.

said wonderfully, I hope it goes that way as you are indeed correct
